# Best way to eliminate duplicates rows after multiple joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I'll consider three simple tables. A, B are my entity tables and C is an intermediate table that creates a many-to-many relationship between A & B.

Schemas:

```
A: (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)
B: (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)
C: (
  A_id INTEGER, 
  B_id INTEGER, 
  FOREIGN KEY(A_id) REFERENCES A(id), 
  FOREIGN KEY(B_id) REFERENCES B(id)
)
```

Now, consider the below query

```sql
SELECT
  A.id
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN C
  ON (A.id = C.A_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
  ON (C.B_id = B.id)
WHERE ...;
```

This query would result in duplicate values of A.id, which is expected because C might have multiple rows associated with each row of A. My question is what's the best way to eliminate these duplicates and get the A records. I only need the A records.

I am aware of two ways,

```sql
-- Using DISTINCT
SELECT
  DISTINCT(A.id), ...
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN C
  ON (A.id = C.A_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
  ON (C.B_id = B.id)
WHERE ...
  ORDER BY A.id;
```

And

```sql
-- Or using A.id IN (above query)/ A.id = Any(above query)
SELECT 
  ...
FROM A 
WHERE A.id IN (
  SELECT
    A.id
  FROM A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN C
    ON (A.id = C.A_id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN B
    ON (C.B_id = B.id)
  WHERE ...
);
```

I'm using PostgreSQL. I need to include all the tables for filtering, so not joining a table cannot be considered as an improvement. I've analyzed both the queries but I still feel there might be a better way to do this(in terms of performance).

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: It depends a lot on what the conditions are.  Why are you using a `left join` with a `where` clause?

Comment: Because I need the attrs from B & A in the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `exists`:

```
SELECT A.id
FROM A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM C JOIN
                   B
                   ON C.B_id = B.id
              WHERE A.id = C.A_id AND . . . 
             )
```

Comment: I'll give this a try on the actual tables. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try following query:

```sql
SELECT
    a.* -- or whatever columns you need of a
FROM a
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM c
    WHERE c.a_id = a.id
)
```

Note, that there is no need to join table `b` as the existence of the row in `c` always guarantees for the row in `b` and you do not need any information contained in this row/table.

Perhaps even more clean might be:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.* -- or whatever columns you need of a
FROM a
LEFT JOIN c
```

You can have a look at the query plans and execution times using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <query>`. Perhaps this gives you a hint on what to use best.
But be aware of caching, repeat both queries multiple times this way to see comparable results.

Comment: Actually, this is just an example, the real query joins around 4 tables and I need data of all 4 in the WHERE clause, so the second approach not feasible.

Comment: Please edit the question to mirror your real needs, so you can get a feasible answer. @Crash0v3rrid3